# How can I prevent geom_rect adding a horizontal line of pixels between rectangles?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My rendering code uses geom_rect to display adjacent rows of coloured rectangles but, despite setting the border colour to NA and the border size to zero, there are still single pixel-high horizontal lines between the rectangles.

I am working in R v4.0.3 on macOS v11.2.3 with ggplot2 v3.3.3.

Here is some code to reproduce the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)

regions <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                      left = c(0, 4, 0, 3), right = c(4, 5, 3, 5),
                      top = c(6, 6, 2, 2), bottom = c(2, 2, 0, 0),
                      colour = c("lightgrey", "gold", "lightgrey", "blue"))

plot <- ggplot() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") +
  geom_rect(data = regions, 
            mapping = aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, 
                          ymin = bottom, ymax = top, 
                          fill = colour), 
            colour = NA, size = 0) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  geom_text(data = regions, 
            mapping = aes(x = left + (right - left) / 2, 
                          y = bottom + (top - bottom) / 2, 
                          label = name)) +
  xlab("") + ylab("")

ggsave("~/Desktop/borders.png", plot = plot, 
       units = "cm", width = 10, height = 10, dpi = 600)
```

The image looks like this:

[image: this]

When I zoom in to show the problem, the horizontal lines look like this:

[image: this]

I know it's faint but when I render lots of rows of rectangles together the problem results in subtle horizontal banding which distracts the viewer's attention from the data that I'm presenting.

I've tried printing the image as well as viewing it on Windows 7 (in MS Paint) and the lines are still visible.

This is probably the moment when someone explains that I don't understand image formats or antialiasing or something.  That's fine :-)  If the problem 'is' antialiasing, can I remove it for the geom_rect layer but keep it for everything else?

Thanks in advance, you lovely people.

Edit: using `antialias = "none"` in the `ggsave()` call removes the lines from the rectangles but also make the text look bad since that is no longer antialiased either.  Can antialiasing be controlled at the level of individual geoms?

Comment: Thanks for inlining the images for me, @slamballais, much appreciated!